# How to use PHP Autoloader in multiple files?

Tags: php, autoloader

I currently try to replace the requires and require_once's in my project by a autoloader. I'm working with the MVC model and need to autoload a lot of files.

**File1:** My autoloader class/function looks like this:

```
<?php

class Autoloader {

    static public function loadEverything() {

        $root = realpath($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]);
        require_once $root . "/src/Model/Device.php";
        require_once $root . "/src/Model/Employee.php";
        require_once $root . "/src/Model/User.php";
        require_once $root . "/src/Controller/Controller.php";
    }

}
```

**File2:** And the file I use this files in looks like this:

```
$root = realpath($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]);
require_once $root . "/src/Model/Autoloader.php";
spl_autoload_register('Autoloader::loadEverything');
```

But that doesn't work. How do I activate that autoload in File2? I don't get it. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is what you do when you want to autoload your classes:

```
function my_autoloader($class) {
    include $root . 'classes/' . $class . '.class.php';
}

spl_autoload_register('my_autoloader');
```

If you want to load anything else you can write a new function that gets called where you put all your `require_once` stuff.

This works:

```
class Autoloader {

    static public function loadEverything() {
        $root = realpath($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]);

        //Autoloading classes
        spl_autoload_register(function ($class) {
            $root . 'Model/' . $class . '.php';
        });

        //Manually load needed files
        require_once $root . "/src/Model/Device.php";
        require_once $root . "/src/Model/Employee.php";
        require_once $root . "/src/Model/User.php";
        require_once $root . "/src/Controller/Controller.php";
    }

}

Autoloader::loadEverything();
```

If you are new to mvc, you can watch the videos from Codecourse on youtube. He has like 25 videos about a mvc application and he explains everything so nice.

Comment: But do I insert that in my autoloader class or in the file where I want to use the required files?

Comment: You can put the function in your class or not and this `spl_autoload_register('my_autoloader');` in your `loadEverything()` function.

Comment: I did that, but I think I made a mistake because I still get an error. Could you check if I inserted it correct? https://hastebin.com/uxuhinofub.js

Comment: @janisch `$root = realpath($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]);` doesn't need to be in the autoloader function, because if you define it in the autoloader function, you can't use it when you do `require_once $root . "/src/Model/Device.php";`